# Looking up values from one data.frame to create a column in another, using dates in the current data.frame

Tags: r, date, dataframe, lookup, addition

I'm trying to select information from one data.frame to import into columns of another. The values to be selected can be identified by row and column, and are dependent on calculations from the existing columns of the output data.frame. I'm getting stuck because there are numerous steps to combine, and despite having broken it down and got parts to work, I can't get the final combination together.

My look-up data.frame is of the form:

```
Date.Time <- rep(c("2014/05/06_pm", "2014/05/07_am", "2014/05/07_pm", "2014/05/08_am"), 4)
Nest <- c(rep("WTSN08", 4), rep("WTSN26", 4), rep("WTSN07", 4), rep("WTSN06", 4))
value <- c(25, 24, 26, 25, 27, 27, 28, 26, 21, 23, 21, 20, 25, 28, 26, 28)
df <- data.frame(Date.Time, Nest, value)
library(reshape)
Lookup <- cast(df, Nest ~ Date.Time, row.names = FALSE)
```

My output data.frame is of the form:

```
Nest <- rep(c("WTSN08","WTSN26","WTSN07","WTSN06"), 2)
Hatch <- as.Date(rep(c("2014/04/28", "2014/04/29", "2014/04/29", "2014/04/25"),2))
Age <- c(9.5, 8.0, 8.5, 13.0, 10.0, 9.5, 9.5, 12.0)
Output <- data.frame(Nest, Hatch, Age)
```

What I need to do is create a new column, `Output$T-1`, which adds `Output$Age` to the date given in `Output$Hatch`, recognising an age ending in ".5" as an afternoon, and returns the value from Lookup corresponding to the time slot BEFORE that read in Output, e.g.:

For WTSN08: `2014/04/28 + 9.5 = 2014/05/07_pm`; therefore return value for WTSN08 at `2014/05/07_am` = `24`

A second column will then compute the same thing, but return the value 2 time slots before (e.g. 2014/05/06_pm for the above).

I have found that

```
Output$Hatch + Output$Age
```

will output the correct date, and that

```
paste(as.character(Output$Hatch + Output$Age), "am", sep = "_")
```

will append "_am" to a date, such that a value can be looked up thus

```
Lookup[Lookup$Nest == "WTSN08",as.character(paste(as.character(Output$Hatch + Output$Age), "am", sep = "_"))]
```

and that

```
grepl("^.+(.5)$",Output$Age)
```

will return the locations of ages ending in ".5"

I have tried to wrap this in an ifelse command, initially to just get the value for the computed time slot (rather than worrying about subtracting days yet), to form the column:

```
Output$T <- ifelse(grepl("^.+(.5)$",WTS_w$Age),
    Max.Ts[Max.Ts$Nest == as.character(WTS_w$Nest), paste(as.character(WTS_w$Hatch + WTS_w$Age), "pm", sep = "_")],
    Max.Ts[Max.Ts$Nest == as.character(WTS_w$Nest), paste(as.character(WTS_w$Hatch + WTS_w$Age), "am", sep = "_")]
)
```

or using "match" for the row lookup, but to no avail.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it might be informative to let users know that I have solved this.

I ended up leaving the `Lookup` data.frame in the melted form i.e.:

```
df <- data.frame(Date.Time, Nest, value)
```

I then used `paste` to combine the `Nest` and `Date.Time` columns

```
paste(df$Nest, df$Date.Time, sep = "_")
```

so that they could be matched to the `Output` data.frame following the addition I had already achieved.

Putting this together with an `ifelse` command wrapped within `match` gave the value at the current time slot:

```
Output$T <- df$value[match(ifelse(grepl("^.+(.5)$",Output$Age),
                                  paste(Output$Nest, as.character(Output$Hatch + Output$Age), "pm", sep = "_"),
                                  paste(Output$Nest, as.character(Output$Hatch + Output$Age), "am", sep = "_"))
                                  ,paste(df$Nest, df$Date.Time, sep = "_"))]
```

To get the value in the previous time slot, I adjusted the code:

```
Output$T1 <- df$value[match(ifelse(grepl("^.+(.5)$",Output$Age),
                                   paste(Output$Nest, as.character(Output$Hatch + Output$Age), "am", sep = "_"),
                                   paste(Output$Nest, as.character(Output$Hatch + Output$Age -1), "pm", sep = "_"))
                                   ,paste(df$Nest, df$Date.Time, sep = "_"))]
```